# MVC: Create does not work without @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to learn something about MVC by creating a small project. I already have managed to get a lot of things working, but now I am facing something I can not explain.

Basically, I have the usual setup (Model, Viewer, Controller) and my Model database is displayed in a View. Starting with the standard Create-View and -Action, which can be generated automatically in Visual Studio, I intended to change this method, so that some cells have calculated values and do not come from a user input.

This works fine for my *Ready*-column and *Ready-Date*-column, but fails for the *Month*-column. To generate a new row somehow

> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Month)

is needed. If I remove this (like I did for Ready and Ready-Date) clicking the submit-Button doesn't create anything and the application stays on the Create-Page.

My two ActionResults in the ModelController look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //I use this in order to print the UpcomingMonth on the Create-Page
    ViewBag.upcomingMonth = getUpcomingMonth();
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Report_ID,Month,Ready,Ready_Date")] Report report)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //I would like to use this calculation for the Month-Value
        report.Month = getUpcomingMonth();

        //For Ready and Ready_Date it works to set the values here before adding to the db
        report.Ready = true;
        report.Ready_Date = System.DateTime.Now;

        db.Reports.Add(report);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(report);
}
```

And the relevant part of my View:

```
<p style="float:right">
    @*Button to create new month*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")
</p>

<h2>Latest</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*Column-header: Month*@
            <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Month)
            </th>

            @*Column-header: True/False is ready*@
            <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ready)
            </th>

            @*Column-header: Set ready Date*@
            <th style="width: 20%; text-align:center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ready_Date)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @*Cell: Latest Month*@
            <td style="width: 10%; text-align:center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(0).Month)
            </td>

            @*Cell: Latest True/False is ready
            <td style="width: 10%; text-align:center">
                ...
            </td>

            @*Cell: Latest Set ready Date*@
            <td style="width: 20%; text-align:center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(0).Ready_Date)
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I really would appreciate any help!

PS: With ValidationSummary I get the following (no error message):

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code in View, my friend?

Comment: Please add your view code so we can see what's going on there as well. Also, when you click on the submit button, do you see a request being done in the Network tab of the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: 99.9% that `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`

Comment: Added my View.
@CamiloTerevinto Yes, I see a request beeing done.

Comment: Take a look at using `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and/or `Html.ValidationSummary()` in your view. These are both used to show model validation errors to a user. You can still inspect the modelstate in the controller with a debugger as well, but these can be more convenient.

Comment: @JohnH I added the output, but it was empty.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Yeah, I thought about that, but what could be a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your view model doesn't validate. You can see what's error if you add these lines to view.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Errors:", new { @class = "text-danger bg-danger" })
```

Comment: I added the error output. Unfortunately it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what caused this behaviour.

In the setup of my model I defined a validation requirement, which did not allow an empty string. Because I set my data after I had checked `ModelState.IsValid`, the empty String did not pass this check and therefore the row wasn't added.

I solved it by removing the validation requirements of Month.